Band saw blade tension gauge snapped out of place
I have a Sears Craftsman 113.247210.
I was just putting a new 1/2” blade on. I screwed the blade tension knob till the blade tension gauge meter hit 1/2”.
I tried spinning the top wheel to test the blade when, BAM, the blade slipped off like the wheel threw it off and the gauge came out of place.
Here’s a video showing that, now, when I twist the tensioning knob, the whole gauge gets lifted up, rendering it almost useless for reading.
And here’s a link to the owner’s manual.
How do I get it back to normal?
